# ScalaTest assertion mismatch due to Physical Address

Tags: scala, assert, scalatest

I'm running a ScalaTest asserting the right data type is returned by my actor.

The actor named "testActor" converts data from SortedMap[Long, SortedMap[String, Double]] to SortedMap[String, Array[Double]]

The current code is:

```
val data: SortedMap[Long, SortedMap[String, Double]] = SortedMap (1000L -> SortedMap("c1" -> 1., "c2" -> 2.1), 2000L -> SortedMap("c1" -> 1.1), 3000L -> SortedMap("c1" -> 0.95))
val expectedResult = SortedMap("t1" -> Array(1., 1.1, 0.95), "t2" -> Array(2.1))
actor ! testActor(data)
expectMsg(replyTestActor(expectedResult)
```

For some reason the assert is done on the map physical address, i.e.

```
assertion failed: expected replyTestActor(Map(c1 -> [D@60b8a8f6, c2 -> [D@7b5ce015),2,2000), found replyTestActor(Map(c1 -> [D@e7bc1f9, c2 -> [D@5efbc9dc),2,2000)
```

I must comment that in debug mode, when i enter "Expression Evaluation" on a break point the actor message and the "expectedValue" are identicalץ

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the values in your `SortedMap`.

```
> Array(42) == Array(42)
res0: Boolean = false
```

Array does not provide a friendly equal implementation.

Edit: plus, `Array` is a mutable structure, usually not recommend to use them while passing messages between actors.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to add an equal implementation?

Comment: You can try using `expectMsgPF[T](d: Duration)(pf: PartialFunction[Any, T]): T` and define a partial function that performs a deep exploration of the message. You can then use `Array.deep` to really test the content of your arrays.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on how to write the Partial Function as to look within the map and compare the Arrays using Array,deep?